# Django import error with heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-models

I set up a virtual environment for my **Django** project and installed all the necessary modules. Everything works in my virtual environment. However, when I pushed to `heroku` and `run`:

`heroku run python manage.py`

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

In my `requirements.txt` file there is **"Django==1.6.5"**.

Comment: Did you add your requirements.txt file to your repository?

Comment: @NiceGuy Can you confirm it really exist in heroku environ ?

Comment: requirements.txt is definitely in the repository. When pushing to heroku it gives: Collecting Django==1.6.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
         Downloading Django-1.6.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.7MB). When I go to heroku's python shell (heroku run python) and go to import Django it says no module found